# "is violative of" vs. "violate"

Tags: adjectives, verb-forms

> All forms of discrimination on grounds of gender **is violative of** fundamental freedoms and human rights. 
> ([LINK](http://www.indiatogether.org/combatlaw/vol3/issue4/flipflop.htm))

Would a native of English language use **is violative of**, rather than "violate(s)", in the sentence above? If so, how are these two ways different?

Comment: It's worth noting that this cited instance (from the Times of India) probably wasn't even written by a native Anglophone, who would be unlikely to mix the singular verb form *("is")* with a plural subject *("forms of discrimination")*. Particularly since native speakers would realise that "violative" is a relatively rare "legalese" term (not even recognised by my spellchecker), so you'd only expect it in very carefully worded contexts. Therefore I think this is Too Localised.

Answer (score 6):

No *normal* native speaker would say *is violative of*.  They'd say "*is in violation of*".

"*Is violative of*" seems to be used predominantly by lawyers when writing and discussing laws.

However, since the link you cite is in fact discussing law, then *is violative of* is not unexpected.

Comment: Why has the writer used "On grounds of" instead of "about"? Is it to sound more formal or there is no difference between these two?

Comment: @user37324 -- Legalese always seems to involve the most convoluted possible manner of expressing something.  It would take another lawyer to explain the fine distinctions, but in some situations, it's not possible to use "plain English" in such a way that a lawyer can't find a legal "hole" in the explanation to relieve a client of responsibility.